# Windows Service exits when calling an child process using _execv()

Tags: winapi, windows-services, execv

I have a C++ Windows application that was designed to be a Windows service. It executes an updater periodically to see if there's a new version. To execute the updater, `_execv()` is used. The updater looks for new versions, downloads them and stops the Windows service (all of these actions are logged), replaces the files, and starts the service again. Doing that in CLI mode (not going into service mode) works fine that way. According to my log files, the child process is launched, but the parent process (the Windows service) exits.

Is it even "allowed" to launch child processes in Windows services, and, why does the service exit unexpected then? My log files show no error (I am even monitoring for segfaults etc which is written to the log).

Answer (score 2):

`_execv` *replaces* the existing process with a new one running the file you pass as the parameter. Under Unix (and similar) that's handled directly/natively. Windows, however, doesn't support that directly -- so it's done by having the parent process exit and arrange for a child process to be started as soon as it does.

IOW, it sounds like `_execv` is doing exactly what it's designed to -- but in this case, it's probably not what you really want. You can spawn a process from a service, but you generally want to use [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create it under a specified account instead of the service account (which has a rather unusual set of rights assigned to it). The service process will then exit and restart when it's asked to by the service manager when your updater calls [`ControlService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`CreateService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), etc.

Comment: I've misunderstood how _execv() works. CreateProcessAsUser() seems to be exacly the thing I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `_execv()` rather than doing it the windows way and using `CreateProcess()`?

I assume you've put some debug into your service and you aren't getting past the point where you call `_execv()` in your service?